# Replace image without ID/Class with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome-extension

I'm applying an external theme via Google Chrome Extension for a website. The logo doesn't have an ID or a class to call it by and I'm looking for a way to replace it with another image. I feel like there may be a way to get the image based on its size, but I wouldn't know what to do from there.

Comment: If you can link us to the site, we can provide better answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if it's for example in `<div id="something">` you can catch it with

```
$("#something img:first").attr('src', 'http://new.src/img.gif');
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you know what the file name of the linked image is you can select by that using the contains selector.

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/

```
$("img[src~='cats.gif']");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to call `$("img:eq(1)").attr("src", "file.png");`

Where `1` is the index of the image. As waitinforatrain points out below, this is zero-based. From the API entry:

> Note that since JavaScript arrays use 0-based indexing, these
>   selectors reflect that fact. This is why $('.myclass:eq(1)') selects
>   the second element in the document with the class myclass, rather than
>   the first. In contrast, [:nth-child(n)](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) uses 1-based indexing to conform
>   to the CSS specification.

See [:eq selector in the JQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) for more information.

Comment: Note that `eq` starts from 0 whereas `nth-child` starts from 1

Answer (score 0):

You need to first select an element close to it.

e.g. if it is the third child of the element with id `example`:

```
$("#example :nth-child(3)").attr('src', '...');
```

or, if the parent element has no ID, you will have to do it using the direct child selector. If the HTML is:

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <div>blah</div>
    <div><img src="..."/></div>
</div>
```

Your selector would be:

```
$("#myDiv > div:nth-child(2) > img");
```